# Partial least squares classification in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to perform partial least squares for classification using the `caret` package.

My dataset can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2UcSfPZijpGOFBYNV9LZjZzcXM/edit). However I get an error which I cannot figure out how to correct.

Code I have used and error I receive:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",number=2, repeats = 2)

plsFit <- train(plant ~ .,  data = rf.spec.train,
method = "pls", tuneGrid = data.frame(.ncomp = c(1:10)),   trControl = ctrl))
```

Error:

```
Error in data.frame(method = "cv", number = 1, repeats = 2, p = 0.75,  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0, 2
```

When I use `tuneLength = xx` instead of `tuneGrid` I don't get errors. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the documentation of the train function of the caret package [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/caret/docs/train).

If you look at the description of the tunegrid parameter, it says that :

> NOTE: If given, this argument must be named.

The way you have entered the tunegrid parameter, it is not named. so what i would suggest is create another variable and assign the values to this variable and then pass it on to the function.

Comment: @ sidquanto, thanks for pointing that out. So something to the effect of `named <- data.frame(.ncomp = c(1:10))`, and using `named` inside the function `tuneGrid = named`? I will give it a try now